# How to aggregate count of each unique value per column as a row indexed by column header?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a series looking like this:

```
         month_1   | month_2  | ... | month_X
user_1 | label_1   | label_2  | ... | label_2
user_2 | label_2   | label_3  | ... | label_4
.... 
user_X | label_4   | label_1  | ... | label_55
```

I want to convert this into a table looking like this:

```
month_1 | label_1 | count(label_1)
month_1 | label_2 | count(label_2)
...
month_x | label_x | count(label_x)
```

where `count(label_x)` is number of occurrences of the label in the column.

I tried various Pandas aggregation functions, but they all seem to need the column names to be specified explicitly, which is not something I can do given how many there are.

Comment: is the first row's `count(label_1)` count of label 1 just in column `month_1`?

Comment: yes, it is. Practically I'm trying to see how often each label occurs each month.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you want.

Using this sample data:

```
>>> df

0    user  month_1  month_2   month_X
1  user_1  label_1  label_2   label_2
2  user_2  label_2  label_3   label_4
3  user_X  label_4  label_1  label_55
4  user_Y  label_4  label_1  label_55
```

```
df = df.drop("user", axis=1)                         # Drops unnecessary column
df = df.T                                            # Transposes data
df["month"] = df.index                               # Turns index into column
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars="month")                    # Melts data into correct shape
df = df.groupby(["month", "value"])["value"].count() # Groups by columns to get counts
```

```
>>> print(df)

month    value   
month_1  label_1     1
         label_2     1
         label_4     2
month_2  label_1     2
         label_2     1
         label_3     1
month_X  label_2     1
         label_4     1
         label_55    2
```